# Sliders (Famous, Dead, or Wanted) Constant familiarity Question

Tags: sliders

In one form or another.
At any given time.
On any given parallel world.
At least one of the sliders is either, famous, dead, or wanted.
I'm just past season 2 and was wondering why every world they visit this happens?
what significance do any of the sliders have, that they are well known on every planet?

I would assume, that with there being an infinite possibilities of worlds, they would have to visit a few planets where they are ordinary common citizens.

Comment: I vaguely recall one or two where they don't even exist...  But don't forget, Rembrandt was a musician even in Earth Prime

Comment: Jerry O'Connell found a universe where he married Rebecca Romjin. That's far more unrealistic than any universe the *Sliders* visited, even the dinosaur one.

Comment: Very true, James, I just watched the Dinosaur episode 2 days ago. I'm not saying all the episodes are about 1-4 of the Sliders, but it seemed to me there should be some scientific explanation as to why these 4 individuals were chosen (on most planets) as having some kind of fame status). I also kind of felt that the writer needed to keep up with alternating who was famous or else the people playing Quinn, Wade, etc... would get jealous of each other being "too much in the lime-light".

Answer (score 6):

Story purposes IMO. If all of them would be just some John/Jane Smith or someone noone even notices, they'd have a far easier time just waiting for the next slide.

Also, as far as I remember, there's not necessarily a direct continuation of the story between two consecutive episodes, e.g. there might be other worlds between two episodes, we just don't see them, because there's nothing happening.

Noone wants to see nothing happening. We don't see Captain Picard sitting in his chair while nothing happens. You don't see the Simpsons' kids sitting in school, unless it's somehow important for the story.

In the end it most likely boils down to [the Law of Conservation of Detail](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheLawOfConservationOfDetail?from=Main.ConservationOfDetail) (TV Tropes).

Comment: This. There are many episodes where it's clear that they've visited one or more wolds since the end of the previous episodes.

Comment: I've picked up on all of this, and understand completely well that it's all for 'Ratings' and 'Entertainment' purposes. I was wondering if they ever mention why most worlds see, at least one of the group as a main figure for that particular world. As if maybe the entire universe was somehow connected to these 4 individuals and keeping the space time continuum in balance... Or something more scientific than just, entertainment value.

Comment: @GeistvonPA IMO it's simply not the case in-universe. There might be 10 or 100+ worlds where they're not important at all, but then there's a single world where one of them is a billionaire and then only that single world is shown in an episode.